# C# events with Bootstrap <div class="btn-group">

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I'm pretty new to Bootstrap but really taking advantage of it.
What I'm trying to do is to get the click events for a group of buttons in a     . The code is below:

```
     <div class="btn-group">
                <button id="cmdBackupRestoreSource" runat="server" type="button"  class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" onclick="CmdBackupRestoreSource_Click">Backup/Restore Source<span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" id="SqlSvr" runat="server" onclick="SqlSvr_Click">SQL Server (Default)</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="CV" runat="server" onclick="CV_Click">Commvault</a></li>
                </ul>
     </div>
```

A screenshot of what I'm looking at:

[image: Want to get these btn-group click events]

How do I code to get these click events in C#?

Comment: What are you using for the frontend?

Comment: This all is HTML/CSS/JavaScript running at the browser (client-side). You need to issue a request for the server to respond, or write client-side code to handle those as you have right now.

Comment: @MattD -- I'm using a combination of Bootstrap/HTML/ASP.net/C#
Alejandro -- I'm not sure what you mean by that.  I'm somewhat of a novice at this whole thing but am always open to learning new things.  Could you elaborate on your suggestion?

Comment: Are you using straight up HTML/CSS/JS on the front end and calling out to a .Net backend, or are you using ASP.NET MVC, or ASP.NET WebForms?

Comment: No MVC at all.
ASP.NET with webforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the onserverclick event:

```
 <div class="btn-group">
            <button id="cmdBackupRestoreSource" runat="server" type="button"  class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" onserverclick="CmdBackupRestoreSource_Click">Backup/Restore Source<span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#" id="SqlSvr" runat="server" onserverclick="SqlSvr_Click">SQL Server (Default)</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="CV" runat="server" onserverclick="CV_Click">Commvault</a></li>
            </ul>
 </div>
```

And in your code behind:

```
protected void CmdBackupRestoreSource_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    //Your code goes here
}

protected void SqlSvr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    //Your code goes here
}

protected void CV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    //Your code goes here
}
```

The onclick event is for client side functionality in html controls.